# Translating datatable.net using ngx-translate in Angular

Tags: angular, datatables, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate to translate my webapp. I have jquery tables from https://datatables.net/ and when I click on flag to change the language I can't translate the labels of this component.

I can initialize the Datatable with right language, but I can't change it. Here is my table initialization.

```
 this.http.get('https://5dcb25c534d54a0014314ce2.mockapi.io/api/closedbusiness')
   .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
     this.closedbusiness = data;

     // You'll have to wait that changeDetection occurs and projects data into 
     // the HTML template, you can ask Angular to that for you ;-)
    this.chRef.detectChanges();

    this.dataTable = $('#tableid').DataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
      buttons: [
        'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    language: {
      url: '/assets/i18n/pt.json'
  }

  });
   });
```

Comment: What exactly you do when selected language changes?

Comment: for now, I'm doing nothing, because I searched for options and I didn't find anything relevant. I tried this solution (https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/45395/how-to-change-the-search-language-option-dynamically) but without positive results.